# Copy Outlook Email Body to Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, outlook

I have 3 tables in the Outlook email body. Outlook Email can be identified with unique subject and I want above 3 tables to be pasted in each cell of Excel sheet, not in one single cell.

I have tried below python code which is pasting the entire content as text in single cell.

[image]

```
import win32com.client
import os
import openpyxl

# Call a Workbook() function of openpyxl 
# to create a new blank Workbook object 
wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 

# Get workbook active sheet 
# from the active attribute 
sheet = wb.active 

# Cell objects also have row, column 
# and coordinate attributes that provide 
# location information for the cell. 

# Note: The first row or column integer 
# is 1, not 0. Cell object is created by 
# using sheet object's cell() method. 
c1 = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1) 


outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) #Inbox default index value is 6
message=inbox.Items
message2=message.GetLast()
subject=message2.Subject
body=message2.body
date=message2.senton.date()
sender=message2.Sender
attachments=message2.Attachments
for m in message:
    if m.Subject=="Sample Change Log ":# here in my requirement i will change the dates
        print(m.body)
        # writing values to cells 
        c1.value = m.body

wb.save("D:\\demo.xlsx")
```

Comment: Post example of the Excel table

Answer (score 0):

```
c1 = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1)
```

You’ve only specified one cell and therefore it will put all the data into one cell.

Specify a cell location for each email if you want it to be in multiple locations

Comment: Yes. We can do that. but problem with line is....  c1.value = m.body .... m.body gives entire email body text. I want to know, how to parse that email body text. If i  can parse it, I can put those into excel cells. please assist further